# nginx is not serving the www version of a static site

Tags: nginx

I can not configure nginx to serve (redirect?) the www version of my site. The non-www version works perfectly. I suspect this is a dns issue, but I don't have enough experience to know that. Here is my working virtual host file that serves the non-www version of the site correctly.

```
server {
 listen 80;
 server_name  mysite.me;
 index index.html;
 root /opt/www/mysite.me/_site;

}
```

Also, when running any `sudo commands` I get this error

**sudo: unable to resolve host www.mysite.com**

I've also tried adding this block as well but it does not work for me either

```
server {
 listen 80;
 server_name  mysite.me;
 return 301 $scheme://www.mysite.me$request_uri;

}
```

Comment: What is the relashionship between `mysite.me` and `www.mysite.com` ? a typo ? The www version of your site should be resolved by your DNS. If it is not the case, fix this first.

Comment: @krisFR    I don't really understand DNS. Are you saying that I need to change a setting with my host provider?

Comment: No, first i would like to understand the relashionship between `mysite.me` and `www.mysite.com`. Can you explain ?

Comment: I don't really know how to explain the difference. I didn't know the www version wasn't working until I tried it on a whim. What should I go read to understand what's going on?

Comment: Ho no please god help me !! ;) Let's say i will guess for you : you have `http://mysite.me` that works. Now you want `http://www.mysite.me` work also, is that right ?? assuming i am right, please post the results from these commands : `nslookup mysite.me` **and** `nslookup www.mysite.me`

Answer (score 1):

from docs:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.org;
    return       301 http://www.example.org$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.example.org;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the output of `dig mysite.com` and `dig www.mysite.com`. If they both don't return the IP address of your server, then your DNS settings are wrong, and you need to create an appropriate `A record` entry for the missing domain.

After that, you can work with @Midimo example to get the server to show correct pages.

Comment: Why are you so sure it is a DNS issue & not a config issue?

Comment: I looked at the `sudo commands` part in the original question, and that hinted also to DNS problems. It could also be server DNS resolver problems.

Answer (score 0):

Others have answers specific to Nginx, but as far as debugging goes, my bit of advice is to use [`curl`](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) with the `-I` option to see what the headers are for each domain. As the `curl` documentation for `-I` explains:

> (HTTP) Include the HTTP-header in the output. The HTTP-header includes
>   things like server-name, date of the document, HTTP-version and
>   more...

For example, doing a `curl -I` to `google.com` returns this:

```
curl -I google.com

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://www.google.com/
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Wed, 09 Apr 2014 00:45:23 GMT
Expires: Fri, 09 May 2014 00:45:23 GMT
Cache-Control: public, max-age=2592000
Server: gws
Content-Length: 219
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Alternate-Protocol: 80:quic
```

The two key things you can get from this is the `HTTP/1.1` response code which is a `301 Moved Permanently` and the `Location:` which is connected to the `HTTP/1.1` response code and sets the new location URL to be `http://www.google.com/`.  Now, let’s do a `curl -I` to `www.google.com` like so:

```
curl -I www.google.com

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 09 Apr 2014 00:47:28 GMT
Expires: -1
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Set-Cookie: PREF=ID=79631a82c2c7cf67:FF=0:TM=1397004448:LM=1397004448:S=z010eeEdNjG129tJ; expires=Fri, 08-Apr-2016 00:47:28 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com
Set-Cookie: NID=67=e9j_a0lvogCKF-Mt-OdZKlRoMwaGJXis7yA0i0l1zKuh2mz_P5MUCsyzvPVhz9yBY2Wi04XzY2tn8UlqaT2i-rvVHGIAb1l1FwXm4wxvLtNTmSvREavLD6qDLeDBar2r; expires=Thu, 09-Oct-2014 00:47:28 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; HttpOnly
P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=151657 for more info."
Server: gws
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Alternate-Protocol: 80:quic
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

Note the `HTTP/1.1` response code is `200 OK`, which means the URL is good & will load from that point on.

So in your case compare the header output for `curl -I mysite.me` to `curl -I www.mysite.me` and you can debug what’s happening.

Comment: when I use curl the response from www.mysite.me is: Could not resolve host: www.mysite.me

Comment: Then you have a DNS issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a DNS issue. I added a catchall route ( * ) to the CNAME record and it works now. Here is my server block.

```
server {
 listen 80;
 server_name www.mysite.me;
 root /opt/www/mysite.me/_site;
 return 301 $scheme://mysite.me$request_uri;
}
server {
 listen 80;
 server_name  mysite.me;

 root /opt/www/mysite.me/_site;
```